# How to change cache write policy for Intel icc compiler

Tags: c, caching, intel, compiler-optimization

Is there a way to alter the cache write policy while working with the Intel compiler. I discovered that the Intel Core i7 processor 1st-level cache is a write back cache.

My question is: Is there any possible way to tweak the compiler into changing the cache policy from write back to write through?

Comment: cache write policy (especially L1 cache) is much, much, much, much, much, much, much, much, much more lower level than anything anyone is coding on. intel has a very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very good team of researches and has spent a lot and a lot and a lot and a lot and a lot of money on developing the i7 and they decided to use write back vs write through, so trust them on this.

Comment: @HansZ That assumes that one is doing the normal thing. Make the common case fast. If I know that I'm in the minority then I might want to use a different policy. In general I agree though. You shouldn't care unless you are writing on a very low level - OS or device driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From reading [*Understanding the Linux Kernel*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Understanding-Linux-Kernel-Daniel-Bovet/dp/0596005652/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1340910229&sr=8-1), I'm led to believe this is possible, although I've never done it myself.  Quoting:

> The `CD` flag of the [`cr0` processor register](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_register#CR0) is used to enable or disable
>   the cache circuitry. The `NW` flag, in the same register, specifies
>   whether the write-through or the write-back strategy is used for the
>   caches.

It is also possible to control cache policy on a per-page basis, by setting flags in the page table.  I suspect that the Intel compiler will have a feature to specify the behaviour of individual memory allocations; I've certainly seen this on Fortran compilers.

How much of this applies specifically to the i7, I don't know.

Comment: Oli Charlesworth: Thank you for your suggestion. Will give it a shot.